# Find the linear transformation of a matrix knowing 4 linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm stuck with an exercise where they give me 4 linear transformations $T:M_{2\times2}\to\Bbb R$ for 4 matrices 2x2 and then they ask me for the linear transformation of a fifth matrix.

$$ T
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &0\\
    0 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}
=3,
T\begin{pmatrix}
    0 &1\\
    1 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}
=-1,
T
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &0\\
   1 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}
=0,
T
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 &0\\
    0 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}
=0,
T
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a &b\\
    c & d\\
  \end{pmatrix}
=?$$

and I have worked with this situation for $T:\Bbb R^n \to\Bbb R^m$ but never with matrices so I have the doubt that how is supposed to find 4 constants that will multiply de 4 matrices I know to compose the fifth matrix to finally can find the linear transformation of this last one. (I have tried adding up the 4 matrices as follows)

$$ 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &0\\
    0 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 &1\\
    1 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}
+
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &0\\
   1 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}
+
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 &0\\
    0 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a &b\\
    c & d\\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

\begin{cases}
2=a  &  \\
1=b & \\
2=c\\
1=d\\
\end{cases}

and then use the coefficients
$$ 
  2\begin{pmatrix}
    1 &0\\
    0 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}
+
1\begin{pmatrix}
    0 &1\\
    1 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}
+
  2\begin{pmatrix}
    1 &0\\
   1 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}
+
  1\begin{pmatrix}
    0 &0\\
    0 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a &b\\
    c & d\\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

and I just want to know if I continue in this way or I have committed any mistakes, thanks for your time <3

Comment: You haven't stated anything incorrect, but it doesn't look like you're on the right track

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is given can be translated as follows. Denote, in a standard way,
$$E_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix},\quad E_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad E_3=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0 \end{pmatrix},\quad E_4=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
We have $\:M=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}=aE_1+bE_2+cE_3+dE_4$, so
$$T(M)=aT(E_1)+bT(E_2)+cT(E_3)+dT(E_4).$$

Now, we are given that $T(E_1)=3,\enspace T(E_2)+T(E_3)=-1,\enspace T(E_1)+T(E_3)=0, \enspace T(E_4)=0$. Can you proceed?

Answer (score 3):

One standard approach is to find numbers $x_ij$ with $1 \leq i,j \leq 4$ for which
$$
x_{11} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + x_{12} \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} + x_{13} \pmatrix{1&0\\1&0} + x_{14} \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}\\
x_{21} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + x_{22} \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} + x_{23} \pmatrix{1&0\\1&0} + x_{24} \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}\\
x_{31} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + x_{32} \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} + x_{33} \pmatrix{1&0\\1&0} + x_{34} \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}\\
x_{41} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + x_{42} \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} + x_{43} \pmatrix{1&0\\1&0} + x_{44} \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}.\\
$$
Once you have done this, we find that
$$
T\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} \\
= a\cdot T\left[ x_{11} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + x_{12} \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} + x_{13} \pmatrix{1&0\\1&0} + x_{14} \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}\right]\\
+ b\cdot T\left[x_{21} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + x_{22} \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} + x_{23} \pmatrix{1&0\\1&0} + x_{24} \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} \right]\\
+ c \cdot T\left[x_{31} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + x_{32} \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} + x_{33} \pmatrix{1&0\\1&0} + x_{34} \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}\right]\\
+ d \cdot T \left[x_{41} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + x_{42} \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} + x_{43} \pmatrix{1&0\\1&0} + x_{44} \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} \right]
\\ =
a\cdot  \left[x_{11} T\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + x_{12} T\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} + x_{13} T\pmatrix{1&0\\1&0} + x_{14} T\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}\right]\\
+ b\cdot \left[x_{21} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + x_{22} \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} + x_{23} \pmatrix{1&0\\1&0} + x_{24} \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}\right] \\
+ c \left[x_{31} T\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + x_{32} T\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} + x_{33} T\pmatrix{1&0\\1&0} + x_{34} T\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}\right]\\
+ d \cdot \left[x_{41} T\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + x_{42} T\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} + x_{43} T\pmatrix{1&0\\1&0} + x_{44} T\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} \right].
$$
In other words, if $X$ is the matrix whose entries are $x_{ij}$, then we have
$$
T \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} = \pmatrix{3&-1&0&0} X \pmatrix{a\\b\\c\\d}.
$$
So, we need to find the matrix $X$. If we write the full system of equations as a matrix, then we can see that the system of equations can be written as
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1} 
\pmatrix{x_{11}&x_{12}&x_{13}& x_{14}\\
x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & x_{24}\\
x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} & x_{34}\\
x_{41} & x_{42} & x_{43} & x_{44}} = 
\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1}.
$$
In other words,
$$
X = \pmatrix{1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1}^{-1}.
$$